# error after updating entity with deleted properties

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jpa

I am trying to update my entity to remove one of the properties. I am using google app engine datastore for my android project. After making the changes to my entity , I have generated the end point classes as well and my code compiles well. I however get error while I run my code where I am inserting record into my datastore against that updated entity. Somehow it is still expecting the old(deleted) property values. Below is the error message I get

```
java.io.IOException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain <--entity name-property name(deleted one)-->
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: an exception (always) has a stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realised I was not up redeploying my app to app-engine after doing the entity changes and hence was the issue. Also I realised that the stats(not the actual entity data) shown on app-engine datastore admin are not always live. That was making me assume that the delete operation(from datastore admin) had not gone successful.